# Calculate total height through loop Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid

Hi I have a table with n number of rows. I need to calculate the total height based on the row heights. The following a Typescript code:

```
private _getRowHeight(_params: any): number {
    let totalRowHeight: number;
    let maxHeight: number = 100;
    let contentLength: number = 50;
    for (let i in _params.data) {
        if (i != "time" && _params.data[i] instanceof Array) {
            let tempHeight: number = 100 * _params.data[i].length;
            if (tempHeight > maxHeight) maxHeight = tempHeight;
            for (let x in _params.data[i]){
                let tempContentHeight: number = 20 * _params.data[i][x].content.length;
                if (tempContentHeight > contentLength) contentLength = tempContentHeight;
            }
        }
    }
    maxHeight += contentLength;
    return maxHeight;
}
```

Basically the maxHeight is the height of each rows. How can I calculate the sum of each maxHeight or height of each row and assign it to the variable `totalRowHeight`. Please advice me. Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Assuming that you have _n_ rows with a fixed height, what is the problem of just using `rowArray.length * x` where x is the height in pixels? If the row height varies you might be better of using `ElementRef` and `.offsetHeight` to determent the height of the table.

Comment: Unitaro, can show me in the codes if u dont mind

Comment: unitario, actually the row height is not fixed. Its changing

Comment: did it solve your problem?

Comment: Nope unitario. Didnt worked

Comment: Ok, you can post a new question. Could be many reasons why it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the height of each row is not fix (in which case a simple `arrayOfRows.length * x` would be sufficient), then you can use `ElementRef` and `offsetHeight` to get the height, i.e:

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'table-example',
   template: '<table-example> ... </table-example>'
})
export class TableExampleComponent {

   totalRowHeight: number;

   constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {}

   // make sure the view has been fully rendered with ngAfterViewInit

   ngAfterViewInit() { 
      let totalRowHeight = this.elRef.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
   } 
}
```